# Commutative diagrams with very round arrows?

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I have a diagram that has only objects in (1,1), (1,2) and (2,1).  I would like an arrow that goes from (2,1) to (1.2) going around (1.1).  I do succeed in curving the arrow, but not to make it round enough to avoid crossing other objects in the diagram.  Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amscd,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
p^{-1}(V)\ar[d]_p
&V\times Y\ar[l]_\varphi\ar[dl]^{\mathrm{pr}_1}\\
V\ar@/_/[u]_\sigma\ar@/^5pc/[ur]^\psi
}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to teX.SX! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. Sorry, I can't help with the actual question as I don't use `xy`.

Comment: Why going around the upper left entry? I'd simply use `\ar@/_1.5pc/[ur]_\psi`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version using `tikz-cd`

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  p^{-1}(V) 
  \arrow[d, "p"']
  & V\times Y 
  \arrow[l, "\varphi"']
  \arrow[dl, "\mathrm{pr}_1"]
  \\
  V
  \arrow[u, bend right, "\sigma"']
  \arrow[ur, rounded corners, "\psi", to path = { -- ([xshift = -4ex]\tikztostart.west) |- ([yshift = 3ex]\tikztotarget.north) [near end]\tikztonodes -- (\tikztotarget)}]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I never used tikz (or tikz-cd) for the commutative diagrams, but it looks like I should

Comment: @Tanda It is very intuitive to use, specially if you're familiar with `xy`, plus it adds all the power of `tikz` for free